# Improve the performance of excel vba while using search

Tags: excel, vba

I have 400 000 records in two sheets with 5 columns each with data in column A being the unique identifier. Order of the columns in both the sheets is same. I am trying to search for record that exists in Sheet1 and find it in Sheet2. If found, I need to compare the data of that record with the one in sheet2. Mismatched data should highlight the cells in sheet1 and copy the entire row in sheet 3.

My macro works successfully for small set of data but it gets hanged with large data and excel gets closed automatically.

I tried commenting the highlighting of cells and only copying the row and also separating only 25000 records but could see the same performance issue as stated earlier.

```
Sub CompareSheets()

    Dim wS As Worksheet, wT As Worksheet, RS As Worksheet
    Dim intSheet1Column As Integer, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, FoundRow As Long

    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set RS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    RS.Cells.ClearContents
    RS.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    wS.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy RS.Range("A1")

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To wS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       For j = 2 To wT.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       If InStr(1, wT.Range("A" & j).Value, wS.Range("A" & i).Value) > 0 Then
                Match = "FOUND"
                FoundRow = j
       Exit For
       End If
       Next


       If Match = "FOUND" Then
           CopyFlag = False
            For intSheet1Column = 2 To wS.UsedRange.Columns.Count
               If wS.Cells(i, intSheet1Column).Value <> wT.Cells(FoundRow, intSheet1Column).Value Then
                  wS.Cells(i, intSheet1Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                  CopyFlag = True
                  k = RS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
               End If
            Next
                  If CopyFlag = True Then
                        wS.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy RS.Range("A" & k + 1)
                  End If
       End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Validation Complete"
End Sub
```

Excel gets hanged and closes off automatically.

Comment: Have a look at [FIND](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/).  Much faster than checking each cell.

Comment: And comment out the On Error line and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code using `FIND`:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim sht1_LastCell As Range
    Dim sht1_Index As Range, rValue As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim bMismatch As Boolean
    Dim lRowToCopy As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sht1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set sht2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set sht3 = .Worksheets("Sheet3")
    End With

    'Return a reference to the last cell on Sheet1.
    Set sht1_LastCell = LastCell(sht1)

    With sht1
        'Look at each cell in Sheet1 Column A
        For Each sht1_Index In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(sht1_LastCell.Row, 1))

            'Ensure the mismatch flag is set to FALSE.
            bMismatch = False

            'Find a match in Sheet2 Column A
            Set rFound = sht2.Columns(1).Find( _
                What:=sht1_Index, _
                After:=sht2.Columns(1).Cells(1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlNext)

            'If value is found then compare.
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                'Check each column, excluding column A:
                'OFFSET by 1 column to column B.
                'RESIZE single cell range to all cells from B to last column.
                For Each rValue In sht1_Index.Offset(, 1).Resize(, sht1_LastCell.Column - 1)

                    'To reference the correct cell on Sheet2 use the row number that was found
                    'and the column number from the value being looked at.
                    If rValue <> sht2.Cells(rFound.Row, rValue.Column) Then
                        rValue.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        lRowToCopy = rValue.Row
                        bMismatch = True
                    End If
                Next rValue
            End If

            'Copy the data from Sheet1 to the last row (+1 so it doesn't overwrite the last row) on Sheet3.
            If bMismatch Then
                sht1.Rows(lRowToCopy).Copy Destination:=sht3.Cells(LastCell(sht3).Row + 1, 1)
            End If

        Next sht1_Index
    End With

End Sub

'UsedRange can return an incorrect reference in certain circumstances.
'This function will always return a reference to the last cell containing data.
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next
        With wrkSht
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        End With

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. This worked perfectly. Performance has improved much better now using for each.

Comment: Using the above code, 4,00,000 records has the same issue - excel closes automatically after sometime. Took 25 minutes for 25,000 records. I would be grateful if you can help me improve the performance even more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A few thing i noticed looking at your code:
Here:

```
            For intSheet1Column = 2 To wS.UsedRange.Columns.Count
               If wS.Cells(i, intSheet1Column).Value <> wT.Cells(FoundRow, intSheet1Column).Value Then
                  wS.Cells(i, intSheet1Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                  CopyFlag = True
                  k = RS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                  Exit For '<------ added
               End If
            Next
```

After the if Statement is entered for the first time you might aswell add an exit for, as CopyFlag is not going to get any truer.

The next and probably more important thing is, you don't reset Match in the second if statement, that means, after the first match is found, it will go into the If statement `If  Match="Found" Then` for every single subsequent `i`. Is that intentional? If not you could add something like:

```
       If Match = "FOUND" Then
           CopyFlag = False
            For intSheet1Column = 2 To wS.UsedRange.Columns.Count
               If wS.Cells(i, intSheet1Column).Value <> wT.Cells(FoundRow, intSheet1Column).Value Then
                  wS.Cells(i, intSheet1Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                  CopyFlag = True
                  k = RS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
               End If
            Next
                  If CopyFlag = True Then
                        wS.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy RS.Range("A" & k + 1)
                  End If
            Match="" '<------ added
       End If
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.I did not change the 1st line that you have added - Exit For as I need to validate all the columns. I have included the 2nd modification that you suggested but the performance issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I use arrays and a function for searching the id in the second sheet.. If the ID column is sorted we can do much better..

```
Sub CompareSheets()

Dim sh1         As Worksheet
Dim sh2         As Worksheet
Dim sh3         As Worksheet
Dim arr1        As Variant
Dim arr2        As Variant
Dim Row1        As Long
Dim Row2        As Long
Dim Row3        As Integer
Dim o           As Long
Dim nOfColumns  As Integer
Dim myId        As String

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

nOfColumns = 5
Row3 = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Here I start from second row assuming there's columns header
With sh1
    arr1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row, nOfColumns)).Value
End With

With sh2
    arr2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row, nOfColumns)).Value
End With

For Row1 = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)

    myId = arr1(Row1, 1) ' I assume that ID is in column 1
    Row2 = FindRow(arr2, myId)

    If Row2 < 0 Then
        ' Format the sh1 row not founded
        With sh1
            .Range(.Cells(Row1 + 1, 1), .Cells(Row1 + 1, UBound(arr1, 2))).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End With
        ' Put the row not founded in sh3
        With sh3
            For o = LBound(arr1, 2) To UBound(arr1, 2)
                .Cells(Row3, o).Value = arr1(Row1, o)
            Next o
            Row3 = Row3 + 1
        End With
    End If

Next Row1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Erase arr1
Erase arr2
Set sh1 = Nothing
Set sh2 = Nothing
Set sh3 = Nothing

End Sub

Function FindRow(ByRef myArray As Variant, _
            ValueToSearch As Variant, _
            Optional IndexToSearchIn As Long = 1) As Long

FindRow = -1
If Not IsArray(myArray) Then Exit Function

Dim lB          As Long
Dim uB          As Long
Dim Counter     As Long

lB = LBound(myArray, 1)
uB = UBound(myArray, 1)

For Counter = lB To uB
    If myArray(Counter, IndexToSearchIn) = ValueToSearch Then
        FindRow = Counter
        Exit Function
    End If
Next Counter

End Function
```